# OpenGL, Showing Text and getting values using C

Tags: c, opengl, variable-assignment

This has been my problem since I started using openGL.

What code am I going to use to show text and get value. I could not use printf and scanf and my only header file is glut.h.

Answer (score 3):

> This has been my problem since I started using openGL.
>   What code am I going to use to show text

Difficult subject, because OpenGL itself doesn't deal with text output. You can:

- render text to an image and display that
- create a texture atlas from the glyphs of a font, then render from that font texture
- draw the font glyph outlines as geometry

If you Google "OpenGL font rendering" you'll get a large number of results of papers on the topic. Recent and old ones alike.

> and get value.

Not with OpenGL. OpenGL is a drawing API. You send it points, lines and triangles, and it draws nice pictures for you. User input is outside the scope of OpenGL. That's on part of the GUI system. Most likely one of

- Windows GDI
- MacOS Cocoa
- X11

Standard user input event processing applies. Usually one uses a toolkit like Qt, GTK or similar. Those toolkits deal with user input processing through their event mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

http://linux.die.net/man/3/glutstrokestring
How about this?

```
#include <openglut.h>
glutStrokeString(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, "I will draw this string at the origin of the model");
```

Comment: You need openglut or freeglut. Glut has no text drawing functions.